# How to read system defined capabilities for an agent in a tfs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-pipelines, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I want to read my Msbuild path from my self hosted build agent as system defined capabilities, is there any way out to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that information by leveraging the [Agents - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) API call and specifying `includeCapabilities=true` on the parameter list.

Worth noting that if you add new capabilities (like installing nodejs for example), you will have to restart the agent for the capabilities to show available.

Comment: Yes, correct! I had figured it out. But thanks anyway @matt